Problem with redirect to public with Laravel in subfolder
I would like to put some Laravel projects in a subfolder but I have a problem. The example path is /var/www/html/laravelA and /var/www/html/laravelB. When I go to localhost/laravelA I see the file listing. I tried using standard htaccess to redirect to public
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA].

but is use causes a 404 apache2 error. I am running on apache2 installed on Debian.
I trying use this htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

but Laravel show 404 if there is no public in the url

You are "in" localhost/laravelA already, so the REQUEST_URI to check against will not start with /public/, but /laravelA/public/

I changed to
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /laravelA/public/$1 [L].
but now Laravel shows 404 and requires adding public to the address

I was talking about the REQUEST_URI that gets checked in the RweriteCond.

I think I understand what's going on (my full request address is /laravelA/public and I'm trying to redirect as if it's just public) but I don't know how to change htaccess so that entering /laravelA redirects automatically to public without public in the address and starts the project

Do you have this .htaccess in the laravelA folder, or the parent one? And do you need this exact kind of setup for some particular reason? Setting up individual VirtualHosts for each separate project, usually works quite a bit smoother ...

Htaccess is located separately in the root folder of each laravel. I know vhost would be a better idea but unfortunately it won't work. I have a local server at home that I can access via ip for example 192.168.0.100. I want to be able to run several projects on it and access them on the local network so I want to use folders for example 192.168.0.100/laravelA and 192.168.0.100/laravelB.

Can't tell what exactly is going on, from the outside. When in doubt, I would recommend to enable some rewrite logging, then you will be able to retrace in detail, what exactly happens "under the hood."

I added an index.php file to laravel's head directory with the following content
require DIR.'/public/index.php';
and currently Laravel is running from a subfolder without public in the address
